# In SFTP Transfer a file to one remote folder and need to delete the same file in another remote folder

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl, spring-integration-sftp

Using Publish subscribe ,I'm Pushing local file to multiple remote folders (remoteDirectory1,remoteDirectory2(Copy to remote success and archive folder)) 
at the same time I need to delete the same file in another remoteDirectory3 (ex: delete from Remote processing folder)

Using Below code code I'm able to transfer the files to remote but not able to delete the file in another remote directory .

I'm getting confused with SPEL expression  for expression in outboundGateway ...

```
private IntegrationFlow pushRemoteFolder(final String localDirectory, String remoteDirectory1, String remoteDirectory2,String remoteDirectory3,String adapterName, String filePattern, String fileRenameExpression) {

    return IntegrationFlows
            .from(Files.inboundAdapter(Paths.get(localDirectory).toFile())
                            .regexFilter(filePattern)
                            .preventDuplicates(false),
                    e -> {
                        e.poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(SftpProperties.getPollerIntervalMs())
                                .maxMessagesPerPoll(SftpProperties.getMaxFetchSize())
                                .errorChannel("errorChannel")
                                .transactional(transactionManager)
                                .transactionSynchronizationFactory(PushSftpSyncFactory()) // moves processed files
                        ).id(adapterName);
                    })
            .publishSubscribeChannel(s -> s
                    .subscribe(f -> f
                            .handle(Sftp.outboundAdapter(PushSftpSessionFactory())
                                    .remoteDirectory(sftpProperties.getRemoteRootDir() + remoteDirectory1)
                                    .fileNameExpression(fileRenameExpression) //.fileNameExpression("payload.getName().replace('A','B')")
                                    .temporaryFileSuffix(".tmp")))
                    .subscribe(f -> f
                            .handle(Sftp.outboundAdapter(PushSftpSessionFactory())
                                    .remoteDirectory(sftpProperties.getRemoteRootDir() + remoteDirectory2)
                                    .fileNameExpression(fileRenameExpression)
                                    .temporaryFileSuffix(".tmp")))
                    .subscribe(f -> f
                            .handle(Sftp.outboundGateway(PushSftpSessionFactory()
                                    ,AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.Coand.RM
                                    ,"'" + mmSftpProperties.getRemoteRootDir() + remoteDirectory3 + "/' + payload.name")))

            ).get();
}
```

The value of string 
`sftpProperties.getRemoteRootDir() = > /home/hari`,
`remoteDirectory3 = /Sample/Processing`

```
....
```

I think Im missing the file name in expression

if i give hard code value "'/home/hari/Sample/Processing/sample.xml'" it deleting the file but Im getting no reply channel error

**Getting following error**

```
        16:57:13.447 [task-scheduler-5] ERROR o.s.i.handler.LoggingHandler - org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Failed to handle Message; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.core.DestinationResolutionException: no output-channel or replyChannel header available, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=local\outbound\Sample.xml, headers={id=4cdd9962-cb42-7bc1-d30e-b999d693b22e, timestamp=1548780989522}]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.BroadcastingDispatcher.invokeHandler(BroadcastingDispatcher.java:242)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.BroadcastingDispatcher.dispatch(BroadcastingDispatcher.java:185)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:89)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:425)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:375)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:115)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:45)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:105)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.SourcePollingChannelAdapter.handleMessage(SourcePollingChannelAdapter.java:210)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.doPoll(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:272)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.access$000(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:58)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$1.call(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:190)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$1.call(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:186)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy94.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller$1.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:353)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor$1.run(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:55)
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.execute(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:51)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:344)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:81)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run$$$capture(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.core.DestinationResolutionException: no output-channel or replyChannel header available
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:355)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.produceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:271)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutputs(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:188)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:115)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:127)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.BroadcastingDispatcher.invokeHandler(BroadcastingDispatcher.java:236)
    ... 40 more
```

Comment: You need to show the full stack trace; where is this expression`/home/hari/Sample/Processing` coming from?

Comment: The code you show is not related to the error at all. Please, be as specific as possible. Otherwise it is almost unreal to help you.

Comment: I edited my question please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please provide version information when asking questions like this; it's a pain having to look through all versions to line up line numbers.

This expression `sftpProperties.getRemoteRootDir() + remoteDirectory3)` is not an expression; it needs to be made into a literal

```
"'" + sftpProperties.getRemoteRootDir() + remoteDirectory3) + "'"
```

Comment: Really Sorry Gary ,  version is 4.3.12.RELEASE..
How to specify the filename ? 
`"'" + sftpProperties.getRemoteRootDir() + remoteDirectory3) + "'" `
Sftp.outboundGateway not fetching the file name from Inbound adapter Do we  need to specifies the payload.getName()like that ?
`"'" + sftpProperties.getRemoteRootDir() + remoteDirectory3) + "'" + '/' + 'payload.getName' ` like that ?

Comment: `payload.name` (or `payload.getName()`) is a valid expression - with `payload` being the object and `name` the property you are getting. For the gateway, you are passing in a simple String, in which case, it needs to be represented as a literal when representing it as an expression. To create the full filename, you need 
`"'" + sftpProperties.getRemoteRootDir() + remoteDirectory3) + "/' + payload.name"`
The current 4.3.x version is 4.3.19; 4.3.12 is quite old.

Comment: Thanks - Perfectly working Gary but Getting is `org.springframework.messaging.core.DestinationResolutionException: no output-channel or replyChannel header available` error 
where i need to set the empty output channel in my code...
I edited my new code updated my error message above ..

Comment: Add `.channel("nullChannel")` after the gateway.

Comment: Great Thanks Gary